# How to add array of objects with same keys and multiple values in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an array with many objects in it, all of them has the same keys and I want to merge them based on chapter name while not losing any of the other values

[image]

I tried different methods, which are lengthy and has not achieved the solution yet, hoping for a solution, which is optimized if possible

Comment: Show JSON of example input and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically for sort your problem of merge and group other data without loosing data of variables you need to try this code :

```
let array = [
  {chapter: 'Case Studies', id: 1, proficiency: 'Basic', score: '0', count: '2'},
  {chapter: 'Determinants', id: 1, proficiency: 'Basic', score: '0', count: '10'},
  {chapter: 'Relations & Functions', id: 1, proficiency: 'Basic', score: '100.00', count: '13'},
  {chapter: 'Case Studies', id: 2, proficiency: 'Intermediate', score: '0', count: '3'},
  {chapter: 'Determinants', id: 2, proficiency: 'Intermediate', score: '10.53', count: '10'},
  {chapter: 'Relations & Functions', id: 2, proficiency: 'Intermediate', score: '70.00', count: '10'},
  {chapter: 'Case Studies', id: 3, proficiency: 'Advanced', score: '0', count: '1'},
  {chapter: 'Relations & Functions', id: 3, proficiency: 'Advanced', score: '100.00', count: '6'}
];

let result = {};

array.forEach(function(item) {
  if (result[item.chapter]) {
    result[item.chapter].push({
      id: item.id,
      proficiency: item.proficiency,
      score: item.score,
      count: item.count
    });
  } else {
    result[item.chapter] = [{
      id: item.id,
      proficiency: item.proficiency,
      score: item.score,
      count: item.count
    }];
  }
});

let finalResult = [];

for (let key in result) {
  finalResult.push({
    chapter: key,
    values: result[key]
  });
}

console.log(finalResult);
```

**Result look like :**

[image]

Comment: is there any way that I can avoid this values array and show all the data within the first array itself? 
`@nikunj-kothiya`

Answer (score 0):

So idk the exact values inside your array but this is an example of how to merge objects inside one array and return all other values

```js
const data = [
  { chapter: 1, score: 101, text: 'lorem 1' },
  { chapter: 2, score: 102, text: 'lorem 2' },
  { chapter: 3, score: 103, text: 'lorem 3' },
  { chapter: 4, score: 104, text: 'lorem 4' },
  { chapter: 1, score: 105, text: 'lorem 5' },
];

function useMerged() {
  let mergedArray = [];
  let otherValue = [];
  data.map((object) => {
    if (object.chapter === 1) return mergedArray.push(object);
    otherValue.push(object);
  });
  return [mergedArray, otherValue];
}

const [mergedArray, otherValue] = useMerged();
console.log({ mergedArray, otherValue });
```